# C# object remains open

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, registry

In a C# 2008 windows application, I am getting the following error messages:

Process 9528 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\red\sampleclient.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-11-222-333\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople
Process 8880 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\red\sampleclient.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-11-222-333\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople
Process 9528 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\red\sampleclient.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-11-222-333\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
Process 8880 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\red\sampleclient.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-11-222-333\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
Process 9528 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\red\sampleclient.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-11-222-333\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed
Process 8880 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\red\sampleclient.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-11-222-333\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed

There is no code in the appliation to use registry, thus the only thing I think can be wrong is something about the connection string to the database.

Here is the connection string in the database to a sql server 2008 r2 database:

The account that is being used is setup for an applicaiton by using a sql server login. The account also has some kind of rights to windows.

Thus can you tell what how you think I can change the connection string to the database and/or tell me what you think can be wrong?

Comment: You've got some kind of security related DLL injected in your process and it is chattering trace info, typically through OutputDebugString.  These are not errors, just trace statements.  Talk to the guy that's responsible for security matters in your company.  This otherwise has nothing directly to do with a dbase connection string.

Comment: This application is placed into production in 'debug' since the application is for a small company. Also the called process is an 'exe'. A dll is not called. Could one of these items be the problem?